# How do you process messages with deadline

Tags: message-queue, publish-subscribe, deadlines

If you have continuous messages generated with different deadlines, how would you process these messages in order of deadlines.
I have implemented by saving message to persistent store. Later schedule jobs processing the most recent expired messages.
If I have to implement this in pub/sub mechanism, how should my queue give priority to deadline time? Is there any queuing solution that delivers messages based on ttl or deadline?

Comment: What is the manner by which this messages arrive ? Do you publish them in batches or  whenever they are produced.The manner in which they are produced matters in knowing when and how to order them on the consumer's side.

Comment: Say the messages arrive by api. Users make bunch of asynchronous calls and say the result of the api is later notified by email.

Comment: @bercovici adrian any ideas?